# Storage account name is required in logicapp

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Created http request trigger and list blob action then in for each created get blob content and create blob actions

In create blob after entering storage account name also still getting storage account name is required as error message and after this I want to delete blob1.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show your flow and the errors at the point where they occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In storage account created blob1 and blob2 containers.

In blob1 sample data is taken and blob2 container is empty.
[image]
[image]
After reproducing issue from my side you have to take **value** as **Dynamic content in For each**  Then you can retrieve previous action content then you can see in **Create blob action** the **storage account name.** as shown in below image.
[image]

logic app ran successfully and you can see sample file in blob2 container as shown in below image

[image]

[image]

**Delete blob action ran successfully so now blob1 container is empty**
[image]
[image]

Comment: If I am not wrong the sample data you are taken is CSV right?

Comment: Yes Sample Data is CSV